# Google App Engine - Your client does not have permission to get URL

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I developed an Android Application that interacts with Google App Engine. Google App Engine pushes certain messages to all users at certain intervals. It was working till Oct without any issues, all of a sudden I started seeing the below issues and I don't get any messages on my Android device from Google App engine.

Any thoughts?

```
1970-01-17 00:42:54.497

Request URL: https://gstockmarkets.appspot.com/_ah/api/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/deviceinfo
Method: deviceinfoendpoint.insertDeviceInfo
Error Code: 403
Reason: forbidden
Message: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"><title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title><style>*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}</style><a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a><p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins><p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/_ah/spi/com.lakshmi.stockmarket.DeviceInfoEndpoint.insertDeviceInfo</code> from this server.  (Client IP address: 41.223.160.246)<br><br>
We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country.
```

Comment: From Iran? We have a lot of users with the same issue, all from Iran...